# How to transform print with formControlName

Tags: javascript, angular

HI I need to change print in front screen of user.
Example if is number 900 I need to print in screen 9...
or if values of input form which I got from backend 10 I need to print 1... or whatever..

```
<input class="select" type="text" formControlName="preparationTime">

this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ 
  preparationTime: ['']
});
```

Comment: right now the value of your formControl is `''` so change that to what you want.

Comment: Okay but when I use existing data for edit ?

Comment: you could listen to the changes on the form control and adjust the value there using a pipe or some other means just dont forget to unsubscribe from it when component is destroyed to prevent memory leaks

Answer (score 0):

Write custom validator or pipe. This is example of pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'reverse' })

export class ReversePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value) {
    let res = value.slice().reverse();
    return res;
  }
}
```

`value` - is value what you want to change;
`res` - result after manipulating with `value`;

This is example of custom validator:

```
function AgeValidator(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null {
  if (control.value > 18) {
    return { 'age': true };
  }
  return null;
}
```

Don't forget to add his to form element:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ 
  preparationTime: ['',[AgeValidator]]
});
```

Comment: I need to print on frontend screen different type..

Comment: Write more info what you want to do with data and for what ?